# c++ tree within an array

Tags: c++, arrays, tree

I'm trying to make an array that hold splay trees. I tried:

```
SplayTree<Node> splayArray[];
```

Then initializing it with:

```
splayArray[10];
```

However, when I try to insert using:

```
splayArray[0].insert(nodeObject);
```

It doesn't work, I keep getting this error:

```
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000018
```

Note that everything works fine if I just make one splay tree and inserting nodes in there.

Comment: `SplayTree<Node> splayArray[];` This shouldn't compile - it tries to define a variable of incomplete type. Show your actual code.

Comment: We're not psychic code readers and can't help you without the relevant code for `SplayTree`.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
splayArray[10];
```

You're not initializing, but accessing.

You should write this instead :

```
SplayTree<Node> splayArray[10]; // Here goes the size of the array
splayArray[0].insert(nodeObject);
```

Arrays have to know their size at declaration, or to calculate them at initialization (for instance `int array[] = { 42 }; // array of size 1`).

**EDIT**:

Regarding your comment, place this in your header file:

```
extern SplayTree<Node> splayArray[10];
```

Then place this in the global scope of your `.cpp` file:

```
SplayTree<Node> splayArray[10];
```

And then this inside a function, it is up to you to call it at the right time:

```
splayArray[0].insert(nodeObject);
```

Comment: I declared the array inside my header, how do I initialize it inside the .cpp then?